# How many days in ISO8601 duration 'months' and 'years'?

Tags: iso8601

I need to represent a duration of 100 days.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations):

> Durations are represented by the format P[n]Y[n]M[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n]S

But for a duration, how many days are in a month? Surely it depends on which month we're in... Ditto, days in a year.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use 100D? I'd suspect month and year are relative quantities, but you could also just specify an explicit 100 days too, right?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm assuming (maybe wrongly??) that each field is range-limited, so you couldn't (for example) specify minutes > 59. If not, then "P100D" would work fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123582/how-many-days-in-iso8601-duration-months-and-years?noredirect=1#comment54060175_33123582), it looks like it's perfectly legal to specify a count larger than the number of units that make up the next "larger" unit, so you could just use `P100D`. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations):

> The standard does not prohibit date and time values in a duration representation from exceeding their "carry over points" except as noted below. Thus, "PT36H" could be used as well as "P1DT12H" for representing the same duration. But keep in mind that "PT36H" is not the same as "P1DT12H" when switching from or to Daylight saving time.

While the example is for hours, it seems like days should be fine too (and as your problem illustrates, even more useful, since months and years aren't fixed quantities). That said, the standard doesn't specify the maximum number of digits for each unit, only:

> Leading zeros are not required, but the maximum number of digits for each element should be agreed to by the communicating parties.

So whatever is consuming your durations must accept at least 3 digits per element for `P100D` to work; that doesn't seem like an unusually high level of required support.

Comment: Thanks. Seems I'm dealing with a buggy implementation. :(

Comment: @Roddy: Ah, boo. Any chance it supports decimal weeks format? e.g. `P14.2857143W` (or some more or less precise decimal definition of `100 / 7`) would express (almost) the same duration in terms of weeks. Not 100% exact since `2 / 7` is a repeating decimal, but close enough depending on precision. Sadly, the standard doesn't seem to allow `P14W2D`, (`W` is a standalone code for some reason) though if your implementation is non-standard, it's worth checking if it does support it.

Comment: Still I don't get it. Is there a difference between 31 days and 1 month? Are they the same? What about 365 days and a year?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: That's the point; there is no uniform conversion from days to months or days to years, because there isn't a fixed correspondence. If you need to represent a specific number of days, use a specific number of days.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see. So the standard doesn't say anything about it, and it can be any of the 29/30/31 values. OK.